# How does Chaquopy work with React native?

Tags: python, python-3.x, react-native, chaquopy

When I look on the [Chaquopy website](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/faq.html), it says it works with React Native. Can someone point out how would that be possible? Is there a way to extract a Python script output into React Native modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Chaquopy in a React Native app, you'd need to:

- Configure your project's [Gradle files](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#basic-setup), [Python source code](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#android-source) and [Python requirements](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#android-requirements) as described in the Chaquopy documentation.
- Create a [native module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-androidhttps://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) to link your project to the [Chaquopy Java API](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/java.html).